# Is Storing User Input in a PHP Serialized Array Secure?

Tags: php, security, serialization

I'm taking user input and writing it to an array:

```
$array = (
   'name'=>$_GET['some name'],
   'text'=>$_GET['some text']
);
```

I'm storing this data:

```
file_put_contents($myFile,serialize($array));
```

I'm wondering, since text and name are user generated, what type of security issues I'm looking at here.

Comment: "Secure" in what manner?

Comment: I'm wondering if a user can inject anything malicious at this point.

Comment: @Howard Zoopaloopa: they cannot (unless there is a bug in `serialize`/`unserialize` which I've never heard of)

Comment: @zerkms, that's what I was wondering.  I understand if someone could rewrite or had access to that file once it is written there is potential for trouble.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa Or created a file ahead of time; writing to the file with `file_put_contents` won't re-create an existing file or apply any default umasks/permissions. (Also, a terribly-configured or already-compromised system might apply an insecure umask upon creation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the write access to a file is limited by your script only - it's perfectly safe to do that.

Comment: Well, that's refreshing.  I'll tick you correct in (10) min.. thank you.

Comment: @user2864740: ... is another story. It would be about leaking sensitive information (and I'm sure is obvious to everyone)

Comment: Which is why this answer is misleading - as it is not "perfectly safe". (I would argue that the entire concept of this answer is "[sic] obvious to everyone", but if it were then such a question/answer would not exist.)

Comment: @user2864740: the question is about safety of serializing/deserializing operation. Which is safe (unless there is a zero-day `unserialize` function vulnerability)

Comment: The question title is "Is Storing User Input in a PHP Serialized Array *Secure*?" Never once did the OP direct the question to an exploit in the deserialziation process, or even use of the data.

Comment: @user2864740: that's right. Storing user input in a serialized form is secure.

Comment: (Maybe the OP will add more clarification in comments. *sigh*.)

Comment: @user2864740: well, formally OP asked "Is Storing User Input in a PHP Serialized Array Secure?" --- and the answer is "Yes, it is secure"